# Highlighting problem in Jupyter Notebook - VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, syntax-highlighting

Lately when using Jupyter Notebook in VS Code to write some assignments for my studies I ran into a quite annoying problem - whenever there is a mistake in my code cell that prevents it from running, the "traceback" (or however you call it) to the place where the error persists is colored with a high-contrast marker (the color depends on the theme used) and makes the content pretty much invisible unless you manually "select" it with the mouse coursor. Is there any way I could fix it without going too much in-depth into VSCode/Jupyter Notebook extension settings?

The highlighting looks like shown below.

[Yellow syntax marker problem.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HBGze.png)

[And another one here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q1D4T.png)

I tried all the themes preinstalled with VS Code such as Monokai, Solarized Light etc., and also a custom theme of my choice called Dracula.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also have this problem.  It looks like they fixed it less than 1 month ago as of writing this, so it may go away if you update to a recent pre-release of Jupyter in VS Code.  Personally, I am going to live with it until the next stable release.

My version of Jupyter in VS Code:
[Screenshot of Jupyter Versions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XiHnU.png)

Screenshot of vscode-jupyter github: [Screenshot of vscode-jupyter github](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZDNGa.png)

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/8697

Comment: Thank you! Installing the more recent pre-release solved this problem, I just got back to it after some time. Have a good one!

Answer (score 2):

This issue has recently reappeared. While the issue is being fixed you can change the highlight colour within the vscode settings.

Open settings and search for `"Workbench:ColorCustomizations"`

[Image of settings page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LC9wZ.png)

Create or alter the `"terminal.ansiYellow": "#eed202"` to a more appropriate value like `"terminal.ansiYellow": "#9b4550"`. See the linked image.

Credit for this fix: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/8717#issuecomment-1241776226

Comment: Thank you the pre-release version didn't fix this for me, but the override here did!